# latex info about tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to use an example of a flowchart ([link to the example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/flexible-flow-chart/)).
In this example the author (Brent Longborough) suggests to change the code to understand it. I tried many modifications, but I can't understand it and don't find any documentation about this code:

```
> % ------------------------------------------------- % Set up a new
> layer for the debugging marks, and make sure it is on % top
> \pgfdeclarelayer{marx} %---------dichiarazione del Layer chiamato marx
> \pgfsetlayers{main,marx} %--per mettere il layer marx come
> principale--- % A macro for marking coordinates (specific to the
> coordinate naming % scheme used here). Swap the following 2
> definitions to deactivate % marks. \providecommand{\cmark}[2][]{%  
> \begin{pgfonlayer}{marx}
>     \node [nmark] at (c#2#1) {#2};   \end{pgfonlayer}{marx}   }  \providecommand{\cmark}[2][]{\relax}
```

Can somebody help me to understand it or to find documentation that can explain me how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TikZ uses the PGF package to define drawing layers. A drawing layer may contain any graphical objects arranged by the document. When the document page is rendered to Postscript, these layers are put onto a stack in the order that was defined by `\pgfsetlayers`. Think of a pile of transparent panes where each pane carries its own drawings.

Now in this example the `\pgfdeclarelayer` declares a new layer named `marx`. This layer is supposed to carry debug markup (the cyan circled numbers on some arrows) and the `\pgfsetlayers` command is used to arrange the `marx` layer on top of the main layer.

The `\providecommand` defines a command named `\cmark` which is supposed to put marking on the `marx` layer. `\providecommand` is a special LaTeX command. Here it will check if a definition of `\cmark` exists and only if not it will define it, otherwise the new definition is skipped.

The example offers two definitions of `\cmark`, one that carries out the marking and one that will just discard the marking. Depending on the order of the definitions you get either the markings or not and you're free to change the order to your liking.

For a documentation of the packages read [the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ).

Comment: I still continue to have some prob with this example. What does this code mean?
---------------------------------------
\node [coord, right=of t1] (c1)  {}; \cmark{1}   
\node [coord, right=of t3] (c3)  {}; \cmark{3}   
\node [coord, right=of t6] (c6)  {}; \cmark{6}   
\node [coord, right=of t7] (c7)  {}; \cmark{7}   
\node [coord, left=of t4]  (c4)  {}; \cmark{4}   
\node [coord, right=of t4] (c4r) {}; \cmark[r]{4}
\node [coord, left=of t7]  (c5)  {}; \cmark{5}   
\node [above=0mm of p4, it] {(Queue was empty)};
\node [above=0mm of p8, it] {(Queue was not empty)};

Comment: I suggest to read the documentation about the \node command arguments and its effects. The \cmark, as already mentioned, places the cyan circled numbers onto the 'marx' layer.